# Gemfile group dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, capistrano, gemfile

In a nutshell, I have a gemfile that contains

```
group :assets do
  gem 'my_gem'
end
```

, a rake task `my_rake_task` that depends on `:environment`, a Rails initializer that needs `my_gem`, and the following Capistrano snippet:

```
task :run_my_rake_task, :roles => :db do
  run "cd #{release_path} && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} my_rake_task"
end
```

As things stand, invoking this Capistrano recipe causes the initializer to raise an error saying that a constant from `my_gem` is unavailable.  How can I either cause the rake task to pull in the `:assets` group gems or add another group to the gemfile so that this initializer stops breaking?  (Note that of course I can just move `my_gem` outside the `:assets` group, and everything works fine, but that seems like the cheap hack answer that I'm sure can be avoided.)

Answer (score 1):

Open `config/application.rb`. Look at the top of it. Comment out this line:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

And uncomment this:

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
```

So it will load your assets group gems when app loading.

But I think that if you need to use your `my_gem` right in the initializer of the application, then you need to move it out from assets group.

You can get more information about bundler grouping from this article: http://iain.nl/getting-the-most-out-of-bundler-groups

Comment: Based on the comments that go with those lines (especially the "uncomment this line if you want lazy loading in production"), that's exactly not what I want.  I guess you may be right, though, that moving the gem outside the assets group might be the answer after all...

Comment: jip, just put the gem into the group that you need it to be in your own gemfile